# Multi-thread the Birthday Paradox

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've been playing with the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), and came up with the code below. The problem is that, even for a small 1 million runs, it can take up quite some time. Since `tick()` is the most expensive function, and is well isolated (I think), how would I multi-thread the `while` loop section?

Coming from a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [openmp](/questions/tagged/openmp) background, I would probably be using `#pragma omp parallel`, but I don't know how to do that in [python](/questions/tagged/python), especially with the `GIL` issue

Are there any other ways I can increase the performance?

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1000000   10.320    0.000   21.736    0.000 sim.py:29(tick)
 24617823    6.931    0.000    9.209    0.000 sim.py:8(getday)
 24617823    2.278    0.000    2.278    0.000 {method 'randint' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
 23617823    2.115    0.000    2.115    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
        1    0.983    0.983   22.967   22.967 sim.py:12(main)
   999999    0.105    0.000    0.105    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
```

---

```
import numpy as np

def getday():
    return np.random.randint(1, 366)

def main():
    # Multithread this section
    popSize = [tick()]
    while len(popSize) < 1000000:
        popSize.append(tick())

    print "Iterations %d" % len(popSize)
    print "Average pop size %d" % (sum(popSize) / len(popSize))
    print "Min pop size %d" % min(popSize)
    print "Max pop size %d" % max(popSize)

def tick():
    days = set()
    day = getday()
    while day not in days:
        days.add(day)
        day = getday()

    return len(days)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code where the `if` clause under main() selects original or mp versions...

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def getday():
    return np.random.randint(1, 366)

def main():
    size = 1000000
    if 0:   # original version
        popSize = [tick()]
        while len(popSize) < size:
            popSize.append(tick())
    else:   # multithreaded
        pool = mp.Pool()
        popSize = pool.map(tick, range(size))

    print "Iterations %d" % len(popSize)
    print "Average pop size %d" % (sum(popSize) / len(popSize))
    print "Min pop size %d" % min(popSize)
    print "Max pop size %d" % max(popSize)

def tick(dummy=None):
    days = set()
    day = getday()
    while day not in days:
        days.add(day)
        day = getday()
    return len(days)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On my 14 core machine run-time goes from 21 seconds to 1.75 seconds which is fairly close to the theoretical max.

There's a few different parallel methods in multiprocessing that you can try.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html *16.6.2.9. Process Pools*

Note that the optional chunksize parameter can greatly impact performance.  With `map` it doesn't seem to be required for a speedup but if you use `imap` you need to set `chunksize` to something like 100 to see the speedup.

Comment: That does the trick. Was shooting for something in the 100 million runs. and it did it in about 3 minutes, taking up a whopping 5.5GB of RAM.

Comment: I tried with multithreading but even with 4 Threads it only uses 25% of CPU. Threading is not a strength of Python, it seems

Comment: You may need to set the chunksize.  I was getting 100% CPU usage on my 14 core box.

Comment: You're doing multi*processing*

Comment: @bivouac0 All 12 of my cores were pegged, cProfile reports 212 seconds for 100 million runs.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you were using `threading`.  With the GIL `threading` is only useful for parallellizing IO.  It's not much use for speeding computations up.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Changed tags to [tag:multiprocessing] since I didn't know the right terminology for it.

Comment: @Drise: normally, threads can run on different CPUs, so multithreading usually is increasing the performance. I don't know why it doesn't for Python.

Comment: @Drise  Take a look at... https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock  In python a thread runs inside of single process but you can use mutliprocessing to transparently `fork` new processes and take advantage of multiple core.  It's just an oddity in the way python was implemented.  Maybe someday they'll lift this (ie.. python 4?)